# c# linq create a third list combining two lists with different item count

Tags: c#, linq

I need do combine two lists in C#, like the following:

```
List1 
    [0]A
    [1]B

List2
    [0]C
    [1]D
    [2]E
```

I need as a result a list like:

```
List3
    [0] A,C
    [1] A,D
    [2] A,E
    [3] B,C
    [4] B,D
    [5] B,E
```

Would you lend me a hand? If possible, I'd like to do this using LINQ.

Thanks.

Comment: @OleksiiAza this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076319/linq-cross-join-query-for-nested-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var List3 = (from f in List1
             from s in List2
             select $"{f}, {s}").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<char> ListA = new List<char>();
            List<char> ListB = new List<char>();
            ListA.Add('A');
            ListA.Add('B');
            ListB.Add('C');
            ListB.Add('D');
            ListB.Add('E');
var result =  ListA.SelectMany(g => ListB.Select(c => new { g,c }));
```

Comment: thank for your collaboration, but the example from @Oleksii Aza does the same with less code.

Comment: @rmszc81 - Actually this version uses less code. Sajeetharan has omitted the `.ToList()` call. Otherwise, and other than returning `$"{x}, {y}"` versus `new  { x, y }`, Oleksii's & Sajeetharan's answers are the same.